# Does the link we provide on various networking websites counts as a backlink?

Tags: seo, google, facebook, backlinks

Does the blog/website address we add on various sites like Facebook count as a backlink in the eyes of search engines, especially Google?

Comment: As far as I can tell, all external links on Facebook are `rel="nofollow"`. So, whilst they are technically "backlinks", they won't _directly_ count towards your SEO as far as Google in concerned. (?)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the the site. Most major sites will do `rel="nofollow"` so there is no benefit. I think networking sites are better for referral traffic and lead generation.

Answer (score 2):

All external links pointing to your site are backlinks (also called inbound links or incoming links).

Several backlinks have a positive effect for SEO and others don't. Backlinks with the `rel="nofollow"` attribute or non reachable for Google bots or from a non-indexed page by Google have in general no impact for SEO.

However, even if backlinks from Facebook or Twitter have the `rel="nofollow"` attribute, they can easily generate direct traffic for your site. Don't forget the only goal of SEO is to generate more traffic.

Moreover, communicating about your site with Facebook and Twitter can improve SEO because Google takes into account likes, shares, tweets, etc.